# What is the internal precision of numpy.float128?

Tags: python, c, numpy

What precision does `numpy.float128` map to internally? Is it `__float128` or long double? Or something else entirely?

A potential follow on question if anybody knows: is it safe in C to cast a `__float128` to a (16 byte) long double, with just a loss in precision? (this is for interfacing with a C lib that operates on long doubles).

Edit: In response to the comment, the platform is 'Linux-3.0.0-14-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-11.10-oneiric'. Now, if `numpy.float128` has varying precision dependent on the platform, that is also useful knowledge for me!

Just to be clear, it is the *precision* I am interested in, not the size of an element.

Comment: "The versions with a number following correspond to whatever words are available on the specific platform you are using which have at least that many bits in them" seems clear.  128 bits.  What was confusing about that?  It is platform specific and you didn't list a platform, making it impossible to answer your question as asked.  Please **update** the question with the exact Python platform information.  Hint: there's a `platform` package.

Comment: "seems clear" -- assuming it also says what happens when no such type is available on the specific platform.

Comment: I've been assuming that the numpy precision is platform independent, so information to the contrary is certainly useful. I *would* assume that float128 maps to something like __float128 internally, but long double is also 128 bits on my system, so it could reasonably be that.

Comment: "assuming that the numpy precision is platform independent"?  Why?  The documentation is quite clear that it's **not** platform independent.  The precision depends on the size of the element.  64 bits is one precision.  128 bits is a different precision.  Both are documented in the IEEE floating-point specifications.  The question you need to ask is "how do I figure out which size my particular numpy is using?"

Comment: What? The question is referring to numpy.float128. Does the precision of that change across platforms? I _do_ appreciate that not all platforms offer that dtype, but it's not so silly to assume that those that do, define it the same way. Would you be so good as to point me to docs that might contradict that? [This page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) doesn't even refer to float128 (but does nicely define those types it does document). I find it reasonable that the type maps to IEEE 754 quadruple type, and that's what I'm trying to confirm (or not).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's quite recommended to use [`longdouble` instead of float128](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-dev/2008-March/008562.html), since it's quite [a mess](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.numeric.general/46380), ATM. Python will cast it to `float64` during initialization.

Inside numpy, it can be a double or a long double. It's defined in [`npy_common.h`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_common.h) and depends of your platform. I don't know if you can include it out-of-the-box into your source code.

If you don't need performance in this part of your algorithm, a safer way could be to export it to a string and use [`strold`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtold) afterwards.

Comment: Does it lie correctly in memory to cast a pointer to a float128 array to long double? It *is* performance critical ;)

Comment: Further to that, reading npy_common.h, it seems to imply the it's sensitive to the platform dependent length of long double (i.e. it uses long double if long double is 128 bits), but my mental C preprocessor is a bit flakey.

Comment: Ok, I've largely answered those questions I think. I *can* cast to long double and everything works as expected. The references above would suggest that float128, if it exists, is defined as a long double, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Further to all those comments, numpy.longdouble is _defined_ on my platform as numpy.float128, which allows me to work entirely in terms of longdouble, which is always well defined.

Comment: @user4815162342 your "down" link is down.

Comment: re down link. i guess the mailing lists changed url. so now we have to find the new url somehow.

Answer (score 59):

`numpy.longdouble` refers to whatever type your C compiler calls [`long double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double). Currently, this is the *only* extended precision floating point type that numpy supports.

On x86-32 and x86-64, this is an [80-bit floating point type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision). On more exotic systems it may be something else (IIRC on Sparc it's an actual 128-bit IEEE float, and on PPC it's [double-double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-double_%28arithmetic%29#Double-double_arithmetic)). (It also may depend on what OS and compiler you're using -- e.g. MSVC on Windows doesn't support any kind of extended precision at all.)

Numpy will also export some name like `numpy.float96` or `numpy.float128`. Which of these names is exported depends on your platform/compiler, but whatever you get always refers to the same underlying type as `longdouble`. Also, these names are highly misleading. They *do not* indicate a 96- or 128-bit IEEE floating point format. Instead, they indicate the number of bits *of alignment* used by the underlying `long double` type. So e.g. on x86-32, `long double` is 80 bits, but gets padded up to 96 bits to maintain 32-bit alignment, and numpy calls this `float96`. On x86-64, `long double` is again the identical 80 bit type, but now it gets padded up to 128 bits to maintain 64-bit alignment, and numpy calls this `float128`. There's no extra precision, just extra padding.

Recommendation: ignore the `float96`/`float128` names, just use `numpy.longdouble`. Or better yet stick to doubles unless you have a truly compelling reason. They'll be faster, more portable, etc.

Comment: also FYI for those doing complex operations. there is a `numpy.longcomplex`.

Answer (score 6):

TLDR from the [numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html#extended-precision):

> `np.longdouble` is padded to the system default; `np.float96` and `np.float128` are provided for users who want specific padding. In spite of the names, `np.float96` and `np.float128` provide only as much precision as `np.longdouble`, that is, 80 bits on most x86 machines and 64 bits in standard Windows builds.