# Setting uniform Numpy dtype of all scalars and arrays (how to avoid downcasting in precision)

Tags: numpy, casting, floating-point, precision, scalar

**Question:**
What is the simplest way to set the dtype of *all* scalar and array variables using numpy?

**Problem:**
As the size and complexity of my algorithms grow, I am finding it very difficult tracing convergence problems due to round-off and truncation errors. I need a way to confidently set precision of all operations to eliminate those errors as a trivial cause.

**Specifics:**
As indicated in the research section, I am mainly having a difficult time figuring out how to set the precision type of scalars to be variable (see below). Even though my arrays have variable dtype, because a scalar may not have been explicitly set to the same or higher precision dtype, down-casting occurs and I lose the precision unknowingly in my algorithms.

**Research:**

[Can i set float128 as the standard float-array in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350342/can-i-set-float128-as-the-standard-float-array-in-numpy)
This question gave me great advice; always set the array dtype to a variable and in your code define that variable as "numpy.float64" or whatever you want. But, how to do this for scalars?

[How to perform precise calculations in Python, regardless of input types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892669/how-to-perform-precise-calculations-in-python-regardless-of-input-types)
This one suggests mapping my scalars to the desired input. But, is there a cleaner way?

What I have been doing is this (thanks to Ophion in his comment below):

```
import numpy as np
prec = np.float96

# a simple example of a scalar that might end up in my code
some_val = 5.0 - 3.99999999999999999992

# my current way of casting dtype of my scalars to the dtype of my arrays
myscalar = np.array(some_val, dtype=prec)

# the suggestion of using mapping:
myscalar = map(prec, (dt,))[0]
```

Comment: You can shorten the casting of scalars of option #2 by `np.array(some_val,dtype=prec)`.

Comment: Even `np.float128(some_val)` works! To cut this down some more: `dfloat=np.float128`, now simply `dfloat(some_val)` will cause `some_val` to be cast as `float128`.

Comment: @Ophion I couldn't imagine a more simple answer. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the following works well:

```
>>> a=np.float128(5)
>>> a.dtype
dtype('float128')
>>> b=a-9
>>> b.dtype
dtype('float128')
```

It might be simplest to write a shorthand definition that will convert this for you:

```
def quad(num):
    return np.float128(num)
```

or

```
quad=np.float128
```

Just to double check:

```
>>> c=quad(5)-quad(4)
>>> c.dtype
dtype('float128')
>>> c
1.0
```

You are creating a [zero-d numpy array](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/wiki/ZeroRankArray):

```
>>> c.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : False
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
>>> np.isscalar(c)
True
>>> c.shape
()
```