# Conversion of a python variable to a real*16 fortran one

Tags: variables, python-2.7, fortran

I'm writing a code in Python that calls some subroutines written in Fortran. When the variables are defined in Fortran as:

```
real*8, intent(in)   :: var1,var2
```

and, respectively in Python,

```
var1 = 1.0
var1 = 1.0
```

everything is fine. But if I define an extended real, that is:

```
real*16, intent(in)   :: var1,var2
```

and in python use

```
import numpy as np

var1 = np.float16(2)

var2 = np.float16(2)
```

the variables take a strange number when passing them to the fortran routine. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: real* is an obsolete nonstandard fortran convention , read this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The Fortran code is an old code written in Fortran 77, which contains such declarations. I modified them to the kind convention.

Comment: you may be past this based on your other comment but numpy float16 is 16 bit (half precision)..you would want float128 if your platform supports it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062562/what-is-the-internal-precision-of-numpy-float128

Comment: Yes, I had already noticed it, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[This numpy-discussion thread](http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Numpy-quadruple-precision-td902.html) from last year indicates that numpy's quadruple precision varies form machine to machine. My guess is that your bunk data comes from two different language's inconsistency as to what quad-precision means.

Note also that `f2py` really only understands `<type>(kind=<precision>)` where `<type>` is `REAL`/`INTEGER`/`COMPLEX` and `<precision>` is an integer 1, 2, 4, 8 (cf the [FAQ](http://cens.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/FAQ.html#q-what-if-fortran-90-code-uses-type-spec-kind-kind)).

Comment: You were right. In order to adapt the quad-precision definition in both languages I've tried to use the BigFloat package (http://pythonhosted.org/bigfloat/) which allows the definition of a quad-precision float in Python according to IEEE standard 754, the same definition used in Fortran, I think. However I keep having the same problem, Fortran variables take a different number than the one defined in Python. Still looking for...

Comment: For the time being I've solved the problem using aux variables. In this case, aux is defined as an 8 bit real (real*8, intent(in)   :: aux1,aux2), and later in the code: var1=aux1 and var2=aux2. However I think this is not much rigorous.