# Python prevent overflow errors while handling large floating point numbers and integers

Tags: python, optimization, sequence, fibonacci, integer-overflow

I am working on a python program to **calculate numbers in the Fibonacci sequence**. Here is my code:

```
import math
def F(n):
    return ((1+math.sqrt(5))**n-(1-math.sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*math.sqrt(5))
def fib(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print F(i)
```

My code uses this formula for finding the Nth number in the Fibonacci sequence:

[image]

This can calculate many of the the numbers in the Fibonacci sequence but I do get overflow errors.

How can I improve this code and prevent overflow errors?

Note: I am using python 2.7.

Comment: Do you have access to `numpy`?  That library has 64 bit floating point types (`numpy.float64`).  It won't prevent overflow, but will increase the ceiling to get there.  I understand some compilers support [numpy.float128](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062562/what-is-the-internal-precision-of-numpy-float128).

Comment: @SethMMorton: Python `float`s are already 64-bit.

Answer (score 4):

Python's integers are arbitrary precision so if you calculate the Fibonacci sequence using an interative algorithm, you can compute exact results.

```
>>> def fib(n):
...   a = 0
...   b = 1
...   while n > 0:
...     a, b = b, a + b
...     n = n - 1
...   return a
... 
>>> fib(100)
354224848179261915075L
```

There are several multiple precision floating-point libraries available for Python. The `decimal` module is included with Python and was originally intended for financial calculations. It does support `sqrt()` so you can do the following:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.setcontext(decimal.Context(prec=40))
>>> a=decimal.Decimal(5).sqrt()
>>> a
Decimal('2.236067977499789696409173668731276235441')
>>> ((1+a)**100 - (1-a)**100)/(a*(2**100))
Decimal('354224848179261915075.0000000000000000041')
```

Other libraries are [mpmath](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) and [gmpy2](https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/).

```
>>> import gmpy2
>>> gmpy2.set_context(gmpy2.context(precision=150))
>>> a=gmpy2.sqrt(5)
>>> a
mpfr('2.2360679774997896964091736687312762354406183598',150)
>>> ((1+a)**100 - (1-a)**100)/(a*(2**100))
mpfr('354224848179261915075.00000000000000000000000248',150)
>>> gmpy2.fib(100)
mpz(354224848179261915075L)
```

`gmpy2` can also computer Fibonacci numbers directly (as shown above).

Disclaimer: I maintain `gmpy2`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is acceptable to you, but you could just use integer arithmetic as calculate the fib number using the recurrence relation (e.g., F3 = F2 + F1).

Since Python 2.5?, you can do arbitrary precision integer arithmetic -- pretty much eliminate overflow problems -- If you try to calculate F(10000) it will doubtless get very slow.

Also, check out the decimal module -- IIRC correctly, you can use in with Python 2.7, you can specify the precision of the decimal arithmetic -- This would allow you to continue using same algorithm -- except for using the decimal type.

ADDED

You can easily overlook that the decimal class includes a square root method. You would need to use this method instead of math.sqrt() since you will need to retain the full precision of the decimal class.

Also sqrt(5) is a relatively expensive operation. Only calculate it one time

Comment: Yes… I have used this method. Part of the point of this project was to calculate the numbers using a alternative method. Your answer is fine.

Comment: Does this help? Or are you still looking for something else. Hard to tell from your comment.

Answer (score -2):

Your statement of *How can I improve this code...* is kind of vague, so I will take it to mean shortening your code:

```
import math
def fib(j):
    for i in [int(((1+math.sqrt(5))**n-(1-math.sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*math.sqrt(5))) for n in range(j)]: print i
```

You can combine both of your functions to make just one function, and using list comprehension, you can make that function run in one line.

You cannot prevent overflow errors if you are working with very large numbers, instead, try catching them and then breaking:

```
import math
def fib(j):
        try:
                for i in [int(((1+math.sqrt(5))**n-(1-math.sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*math.sqrt(5))) for n in range(j)]: print i
        except Exception as e:
                print 'There was an error, your number was too large!'
```

The second one will first loop over everything and make sure there is no error, and if there isn't, it will proceed to print it.

Comment: Sorry if my question was vague. Are there any large number libraries I can use to allow my code to calculate more numbers?