# Numerical result out of range in Python

Tags: python

I am a beginner to Python. I have written a function which calculates numbers that are of the order 10^-15.

While generating the output of the code, an error says "Numerical result out of range". What are possible reasons for which this error occurs?

Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
T=4.32*10**19
i=input("Number of iterations ")
h=T/i
a=[0.01]*6000
t=[0.0]*6000
data = np.loadtxt('/home/user/t.txt')
t=data[:]
def f (a):
    if a!=0:    
        c=((0.75/a + 0.044/(a**2) + 0.74*(a**2))**0.5)  
        return c
    else :
        return 0

for n in range(0,5998):
    k1=f ( a[n] );
    k2=f ( a[n]+(h/2)*k1 );
    k3=f ( a[n]+(h/2)*k2 );
    k4=f ( a[n]+h*k3 ); 
    a[n+1]=(a[n]+(h/6)*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4))

fo=open("a_of_t.txt", "w")
for item in a:
    fo.write("%e\n" % item)
fo.close()

plt.plot(t,a, 'k')
plt.show()
```

The error reads

```
line 23, in <module>
    k3=f ( a[n]+(h/2)*k2 );
line 15, in f
    c=((0.75/a + 0.044/(a**2) + 0.74*(a**2))**0.5)  
OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')
```

Comment: Please show your code and the specific error message (stack trace) that you're getting.

Comment: At some order of magnitude floats will stop working, but I forgot where. Perhaps https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html `decimal` will interest you?

Comment: It's similar to [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29488213/handling-very-small-numbers-in-python)

Comment: Can you write out the entire error? It tells you where the computer messed up

Comment: Can you please tell me exactly what is the value of a[n] + (h/2) * k2. If it is inonvenient I can definitely try to find out myself but it might take a few seconds more

Comment: When n = 34, sorry forgot to add that point

Comment: This is a code for numerically solving a differential equation using 4th order Runge-Kutta method. a[n+1] represents the value of a for next step.

Comment: Actually, I think I  have your answer. Try not using Decimal() and see how it goes

Comment: It was a typo. Corrected

Comment: The entire thing? Wow I feel idiotic good job! XD

Comment: If you really didn't know, you could have printed n in the second to last for loop and found out where it was crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python decimals are stored as 64-bit floats, and as such, have finite precision.  10^-15 cannot be represented using a float.  Consider using the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module.

Comment: Python uses double (64-bit floats) which have a magnitude range of roughly 1e308 to 1e-308, plenty good enough for the OP's stated range of 1e-15.

Comment: @James Can you suggest me how to incorporate decimal module in this code? I am not getting it.

Comment: @user40330 just convert all your variables to `Decimal` by doing `Decimal(var)`.  For example, `T=Decimal(4.32*10**19)`, `i=Decimal(input("Number of iterations "))`.  If you want a `float` at the end, just cast using `float(someDecimal)`.