# Numpy octuple precision floats and 128 bit ints. Why and how?

Tags: python, numpy, int128

This is mostly a question out of curiosity.  I noticed that the numpy test suite [contains tests for 128 bit integers](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/tests/test_extint128.py), and the [`numerictypes` module](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/numerictypes.py) refers to `int128`, `float256` ([octuple precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octuple-precision_floating-point_format)?), and other types that don't seem to map to numpy dtypes on my machine.

My machine is 64bit, yet I can use quadruple 128bit floats ([but not really](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9062562/1461210)).  I suppose that if it's possible to emulate quadruple floats in software, one can theoretically also emulate octuple floats and 128bit ints.  On the other hand, until just now I had never heard of either 128bit ints or octuple precision floating point before.  Why is there a reference to 128bit ints and 256bit floats in numpy's `numerictypes` module if there are no corresponding `dtype`s, and how can I use those?

Comment: I guess you can work out any `32 * n` or `64 * n` precision in theory, but I have to say that about those types being implemented only in tests is intriguing.

Comment: Bear in mind that an `np.float128` normally doesn't have 128 bits of precision - it's equivalent to a C `long double`, which usually has 80 bits on x86 ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9062562/1461210)).

Comment: @ali_m I see.  I learned something else new today!

Comment: It's generally recommended to use `np.longdouble` instead of `np.float128` to avoid this source of confusion. IMHO it would be better if numpy didn't expose a float128 dtype at all...

Answer (score 5):

This is a very interesting question and probably there are reasons related to python, to computing and/or to hardware. While not trying to give a full answer, here is what I would go towards...

First note that the types are defined by the language and can be different from your hardware architecture. For example you could even have doubles with an 8-bits processor. Of course any arithmetic involves multiple CPU instructions, making the computation much slower. Still, if your application requires it, it might be worth it or even required (better being late than wrong, especially if say you are running a simulation for a say bridge stability...) So where is 128bit precision required? Here's the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) on it...

One more interesting detail is that when we say a computer is say 64-bit, this is not fully describing the hardware. There are a lot of pieces that can each be (and at least have been at times) different bits: The computational registers in the CPU, the memory addressing scheme / memory registers and the different buses with most important the buss from CPU to memory.

-The ALU (arithmetic and logic unit) has registers that do calculations. Your machines are 64bit (not sure if that also mean they could do 2 32bit calculations at a similar time) This is clearly the most relevant quantity for this discussion. Long time ago, it used to be the case you could go out and buy a [co-processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit) to speed that for calculations of higher precision...

-The Registers that hold memory addresses limit the memory the computer can see (directly) that is why computers that had 32bit memory registers could only see 2^32 bytes (or approx 4 GB) Notice that for 16bits, this becomes 65K which is very low. The OS can find ways around this limit, but not for a single program, so no program in a 32bit computer can normally have more than 4GB memmory.

-Notice that those limits are about bytes, not bits. That is because when referring and loading from memory we load bytes. In fact, the way this is done, loading a byte (8 bits) or 8 (64 bits == buss length for your computer) takes the same time. I ask for an address, and then get at once all bits through the bus. 
It can be that in an architecture all these quantities are not the same number of bits.

Answer (score -3):

NumPy is amazingly powerful and can handle numbers much bigger than the internal CPU representation (e.g. 64 bit).

In case of dynamic type it stores the number in an array. It can extend the memory block too, that is why you can have an integer with 500 digits. This dynamic type is called bignum. In older Python versions it was the type long. In newer Python (3.0+) there is only long, which is called int, which supports almost arbitrarily number of digits (-> bignum).

If you specify a data type (int32 for example), then you specify bit length and bit format, i.e. which bits in memory stands for what. Example:

```
dt = np.dtype(np.int32)      # 32-bit integer
dt = np.dtype(np.complex128) # 128-bit complex floating-point number
```

Look in: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Comment: 128bit complex number is normal double precision

Comment: float32 is single-, float64 is double-, float96 extended, float128 extended precision float.

complex numbers have two components, i.e. half-width each component:
complex64 is single-, complex128 is double-precision complex.