# Why does numpy's float128 only have 63 bits mantissa?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I'm sure this is a daft question but I'm genuinely puzzled:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> f1, f2, f64 = map(np.float128, (1, 2, -64))
>>> f1 + f2**f64 == f1
True
```

Or more directly:

```
>>> np.finfo(np.float128).nmant
63
```

Exponent appears to have 15 bits, so where are all those missing bits?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that should be an answer I'd say.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yep, reading the docs does help... Care to make it an answer?

Comment: Also see previous answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/17023995/175320. You are not the first to be confused by this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html#extended-precision):

> np.longdouble is padded to the system default; np.float96 and
>   np.float128 are provided for users who want specific padding. In spite
>   of the names, np.float96 and np.float128 provide only as much
>   precision as np.longdouble, that is, 80 bits on most x86 machines and
>   64 bits in standard Windows builds.

So it appears it isn't going to actually use all those bits. I suppose, it doesn't account for the missing two bits, 15 + 63 = 78 if we assume 80 bits on x86 architecture (what I have as well).

Comment: 1 bit is for sign, 1 bit is probably for the explicit most significant 1 (usually) in the mantissa (which is not present in "regular" IEEE754 binary32 and binary64 types, as there it's implicitly 1 always except for the subnormal numbers).