# What drives numerical instability in eigenvalue computations in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, cluster-analysis, precision

Let's say I have a data matrix X with num_samples = 1600, dim_data = 2, from which I can build a 1600*1600 similarity matrix S using the [rbf kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel). I can normalize each row of the matrix, by multiplying all entries of the row by (1 / sum(entries of the row)). This procedure gives me a (square) [right stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix), which we expect to have an eigenvalue equal to 1 associated to a constant eigenvector full of 1s.

We can easily check that this is indeed an eigenvector by taking its product with the matrix. However, using `scipy.linalg.eig` the obtained eigenvector associated to eigenvalue 1 is only piecewise constant.

I have tried `scipy.linalg.eig` on similarly sized matrices with randomly generated data which I transformed into stochastic matrices and consistently obtained a constant eigenvector associated to eigenvalue 1.

My question is then, what factors may cause numerical instabilities when computing eigenvalues of stochastic matrices using `scipy.linalg.eig`?

Reproducible example:

```
def kernel(sigma,X):
  """
  param sigma: variance
  param X: (num_samples,data_dim)
  """
  squared_norm = np.expand_dims(np.sum(X**2,axis=1),axis=1) + np.expand_dims(np.sum(X**2,axis=1),axis=0)-2*np.einsum('ni,mi->nm',X,X)
  return np.exp(-0.5*squared_norm/sigma**2)
```

```
def normalize(array):
  degrees = []
  M = array.shape[0]
  for i in range(M):
    norm = sum(array[i,:])
    degrees.append(norm)
  degrees_matrix = np.diag(np.array(degrees))
  P = np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(degrees_matrix),array)
  return P
```

```
#generate the data
points = np.linspace(0,4*np.pi,1600)
Z = np.zeros((1600,2))
Z[0:800,:] = np.array([2.2*np.cos(points[0:800]),2.2*np.sin(points[0:800])]).T
Z[800:,:] = np.array([4*np.cos(points[0:800]),4*np.sin(points[0:800])]).T

X = np.zeros((1600,2))
X[:,0] = np.where(Z[:,1] >= 0, Z[:,0] + .8 + params[1], Z[:,0] - .8 + params[2])
X[:,1] = Z[:,1] + params[0]

#create the stochastic matrix P
P = normalize(kernel(.05,X))

#inspect the eigenvectors
e,v = scipy.linalg.eig(P)
p = np.flip(np.argsort(e))
e = e[p]
v = v[:,p]

plot_array(v[:,0])

#check on synthetic data:
Y = np.random.normal(size=(1600,2))
P = normalize(kernel(Y))

#inspect the eigenvectors
e,v = scipy.linalg.eig(P)
p = np.flip(np.argsort(e))
e = e[p]
v = v[:,p]

plot_array(v[:,0])
```

Using the code provided by [Ahmed AEK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15649230/ahmed-aek), here are some results on the divergence of the obtained eigenvector from the constant eigenvector.

```
[-1.36116641e-05 -1.36116641e-05 -1.36116641e-05 ...  5.44472888e-06
  5.44472888e-06  5.44472888e-06]
norm =  0.9999999999999999
max difference =  0.04986484253966891
max difference / element value -3663.3906291852545
```

UPDATE:

I have observed that a low value of sigma in the construction of the kernel matrix produces a less sharp decay in the (sorted) eigenvalues. In fact, for sigma=0.05, the first 4 eigenvalues produced by `scipy.linalg.eig` are rounded up to 1. This may be linked to the imprecision in the eigenvectors. When sigma is increased to 0.5, I do obtain a constant eigenvector.

First 5 eigenvectors in the sigma=0.05 case

[image: First 5 eigenvectors in the sigma=0.05 case]

First 5 eigenvectors in the sigma=0.5 case

[image: First 5 eigenvectors in the sigma=0.5 case]

Comment: please provide the code and input/output necessary so that others can duplicate your results, see [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have looked at all 4. I added plots of the eigenvector matrices for illustration.

Answer (score 0):

the computer has an expected accuracy of 14 digits as of 64 bits of float [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514892/how-many-digits-can-float8-float16-float32-float64-and-float128-contain), which means that any result will only be accurate up to 14 digits.

using the below code you can check this result:

```py
Y = np.random.normal(size=(1600,2))
P = normalize(kernel(5,Y))
P = P / np.sum(P,axis=1)
#inspect the eigenvectors
e,v = np.linalg.eig(P)
p = np.flip(np.argsort(e))

a = np.isclose(e,1)
e1 = e[a]
v1 = v[:,a]
v11 = v1[:,0]
print(v11)
print('norm = ',np.sum(v11**2))
print('max difference = ',np.amax(np.abs(np.diff(v11))))
print('max difference / element value =',np.amax(np.abs(np.diff(v11)))/v11[0])
```

result is:

```
[0.025+0.j 0.025+0.j 0.025+0.j ... 0.025+0.j 0.025+0.j 0.025+0.j]
norm =  (1+0j)
max difference =  1.97758476261356e-16
max difference / element value = (7.91033905045416e-15+0j)
```

as you can see, the difference is accuate to within 8e-15 which is around 14 digits of precision, the norm will sometimes be `0.99999999999998`, which is within 14 digits of precision.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, however, I meant to say that the accuracy was much lesser in the first case rather than the second. I will use the code that you have provided to show this result in my question.