# Python H5PY warning getlimits.py:511: UserWarning: Signature <class 'numpy.float128'> does not match any known type

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, numpy, h5py

I get following warning on RedHat 8.8 for H5PY Package:

Is there any way to fix this? I dont want to use **warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")**

```
bash-4.4$ python3
Python 3.11.6 (main, Oct 16 2023, 03:41:34) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> import h5py
/scratch/Python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/getlimits.py:511: UserWarning: Signature b'\x00\xd0\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xfb\xbfOE\xfc\x7f\x00\x00' for <class 'numpy.float128'> does not match any known type: falling back to type probe function.
This warnings indicates broken support for the dtype!
  machar = _get_machar(dtype)
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.24.3'
>>> h5py.__version__
'3.10.0'
>>> exit()
bash-4.4$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.8 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.8"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.8 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.8
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.8"
bash-4.4$
```

This warning is seen only on Linux, Windows is clean.

Comment: Note: Windows 64 bit does not support native `long double`. As noted [here in the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062562/what-is-the-internal-precision-of-numpy-float128), numpy simply adds padding to a regular `float64` on Windows.

Comment: Is there any problem at runtime if I use it with this warning? My tests run fine with this.

Comment: You're just getting that warning on import, right? You're not using any `long  double` datasets? Then I don't see how it could cause issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar issue posted on git : https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/2357

moving to numpy version older than 1.24 may fix the warning.

Looks like a broken support for `long double/numpy.float128` data type from the OS.

You can try other methods to ignore warnings as well.

Comment: Currently ignoring the error helped.